# Python 2/3 compatible way of inspecting method's arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Python 2, to inspect method's arguments, I can use `inspect.getargspec`.

In Python 3 however, a drop-in replacement was added under the name `inspect.getfullargspec`, and `inspect.getargspec` became deprecated.

Is there a way of writing both Python 2 and 3 compatible code that inspects the arguments? I actually only need to find out, at runtime, the number of arguments a method has.

Comment: sounds like a use case for try-except clause

Comment: Or an `if`, check which version is running.

Comment: Sure, would like to avoid that though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a general solution to write Python2/3 compatible imports

```
try:
    from inspect import getfullargspec as get_args
except ImportError:
    from inspect import getargspec as get_args

def foo(a, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

print(get_args(foo))

# Python 3
# FullArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs='args', varkw='kwargs', defaults=None, kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})

# Python 2
# ArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)
```